# Import private and public key with keytool

Tags: openssl, keytool, jks

Generate a 4096 bit RSA private key

```
openssl genrsa -out private_key.pem 4096
```

Convert private key to PKCS # 8 format (this way Java can read it)

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in private_key.pem -out private_key.der -nocrypt
```

Generate public key in DER format (this way Java can read it)

```
openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -pubout -outform DER -out public_key.der
```

I need to import my private key and publish with keytool. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you use openssl to generate the key? Do you prefer cryptic tools like keytool or may be a GUI program like KeyStore Explorer is easier for you?

Comment: These keys are stored in the vault.keystore, in the application that I am processing the keys in that way and I need stored in a jks to obtain them in my application and then send them through a service to another service that verifies with the vaul. That's why I need to import those keys into the .jks to be able to read them with java

Comment: So if I get you correctly you don't want to to this step once but you are developing an application that should do this. If yes then why do you use keytool instead of loading the keys directly using Java? Java can read keys from dozens of formats, not only JKS.

Comment: which I recommend using for this ?. I understand that jks offers security. I'm looking for security for those keys.

Comment: JKS is nothing you could nowadays call secure even if you use a good user defined password that is never stored anywhere. Read this blog post on JKS: https://neilmadden.blog/2017/11/17/java-keystores-the-gory-details/

Comment: I'm starting to read and scared about jks. Thanks a lot